# Confusion related to Kulldorff's scan statistics

Tags: spatial, frequentist, disease

I was reading this [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips18/NIPS2005_0513.pdf&ei=5BFqUe7cFsio0AHgr4GoDA&usg=AFQjCNFKJVOWSum-Q2ww68it_1CmFE1Ppg&sig2=qOxvS2gyWyHeG1xVJ0ryZw&bvm=bv.45175338,d.dmQ) related to Bayesian spatial scan statistics where I came across the Kulldorff's scan statistics.

I have attached the screenshot of the paper. My objective is to find a location of potential disease outbreak.

[image]

I have a little doubt with the formula given in the paper. In the paper it is mentioned that the Fscore of any location is

[image]

My question is when they calculate the F score.

The number of sick people in current location(Cin) = 5
The baseline population is around(Bin) 50
The number of sick people outside current location(Cout) = 2245
The number of sick people outside current location(Bout) = 62475

Call = 5+2245 = 2250
Ball = 50+62475 = 62525

Now if I calculate the Fscore it comes out to be Nan. Is it the correct formula? Any insights.

In the next link I found something like this

[image]

Now even though I use this formula, the value is NaN. It is because like in the case of denominator the prob < 1 and I am raising it to a high power, so it comes out to be zero. So my question is, is it the problem with my data itself? If I plug it into the formula it will definitely come out to be like that.